# Transition animation of Google Street View

Tags: javascript, graphics

I'm interested in replicating the transition animation used in Google Street View using shaders, but I'm having trouble understanding how it works. At first glance, it appears to be a simple crossfade animation, but it also incorporates a sense of movement. Do you have information on how this animation actually functions?

> I've observed a slowed-down version of the animation where it seems to
> stretch on the sides, and I'm curious about the specific name or
> technique used for this animation.

https://imgur.com/a/xim40ma